# Generar token en Google Apps Script cuando el tiempo de ejecución del Script supera tiempo máximo de Google

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive

Tengo un script para identificar todos los archivos que se encuentran en mi drive y me genere un listado en el que va nombre del archivo, URL, y usuarios a los que se les tiene compartido.
El problema es que tengo aproximadamente 2.000 archivos, asi que el tiempo de ejecución del script no me permite llevarlo a cabo en su totalidad.
Vi que existe el método de getContinuationToken(), sin embargo, no se como usarlo
Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

## Respuesta (¿parcial?)

Usa hasNext() para verificar que aún hay archivos pendientes de procesar

- Si es así, guarda la cadena que te devuelve getContinuationToken() usando el servicio Properties (PropertiesService), dependiendo de tu script podría variar si conviene usar las propiedades del usuario, del documento o del script mismo.
- En caso contrario borra el token de las propiedades.

También dependerá de tu script cómo reanudas el procesamiento.

## Ejemplo

Tomado de la [respuesta de Henrique G. Abreu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23243756/1595451) a [Correct usage of DriveApp.continueFileIterator(continuationToken)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22365681/1595451)

```
function listFilesInFolder() {
  var MAX_FILES = 20; //use a safe value, don't be greedy
  var id = 'folder-id';
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var lastExecution = scriptProperties.getProperty('LAST_EXECUTION');
  if( lastExecution === null )
    lastExecution = '';

  var continuationToken = scriptProperties.getProperty('IMPORT_ALL_FILES_CONTINUATION_TOKEN');
  var iterator = continuationToken == null ?
    DriveApp.getFolderById(id).getFiles() : DriveApp.continueFileIterator(continuationToken);


  try { 
    for( var i = 0; i < MAX_FILES && iterator.hasNext(); ++i ) {
      var file = iterator.next();
      var dateCreated = formatDate(file.getDateCreated());
      if(dateCreated > lastExecution)
        processFile(file);
    }
  } catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }

  if( iterator.hasNext() ) {
    scriptProperties.setProperty('IMPORT_ALL_FILES_CONTINUATION_TOKEN', iterator.getContinuationToken());
  } else { // Finished processing files so delete continuation token
    scriptProperties.deleteProperty('IMPORT_ALL_FILES_CONTINUATION_TOKEN');
    scriptProperties.setProperty('LAST_EXECUTION', formatDate(new Date()));
  }
}

function formatDate(date) { return Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); }

function processFile(file) {
  var id = file.getId();
  var name = file.getName();
  //your processing...
  Logger.log(name);
}
```